How can I have jOOQ add Nullable annotations for generated Records?
I can use <nullableAnnotation>true</nullableAnnotation> in my pom.xml to have Nullable annotations added to generated POJOs but this seems to be only working if I generated classes, not records.
Is there a way to have nullable/non-nullable annotations on record fields?

@Lukas Eder any thoughts on this?
